Making a multiplication table as 2 arrays
I am currently trying to make a multiplication table of 10 with 2 nested for loops
It works somewhat, but the first indices aren't working as intended:
my code:

var multiplicationTable = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    multiplicationTable[i] = [i]
     for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        multiplicationTable[i][j] = i*j
    }
}


result:

[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]

[3, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]

[4, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]

[5, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]

[6, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60]

[7, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70]

[8, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80]

[9, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90]

[10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

I don't understand why the first index of each array is the same as the second,
I want to create this without that first index.
Help and how you solved it would be amazing, thank you very much!

That comes from multiplicationTable[i] = [i]. That fills in multiplicationTable[i][0], then the inner loop adds indexes 1 through 10.

Remember that array indexes start at 0, not 1.

You could initialize it to [0], since that's the correct result for i * 0.

Hey, I dont think I understand
What do I reset to [0]
I made the first indices be 1 because then I can use them as the numbers for the multiplication itself

Array indexes start at 0. So subtract 1 from i and j to get the appropriate array indexes.


var multiplicationTable = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  multiplicationTable[i-1] = []
  for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    multiplicationTable[i-1][j-1] = i * j
  }
}

console.log(multiplicationTable);




Now I got it! I need to access the table in indices 0, but still use my original multiplication with the current i and j
Thank you so much!

Here is another approach, using nested Array.map() calls on index arrays created by utility function indArr(n):


// create the utility function indArr:
const indArr=n=>Array(n).fill(0).map((_,i)=>i),
  n=20,
  res=
    indArr(n).map(i=>
      indArr(n).map(j=>
        (i+1)*(j+1)
    ));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;}



The fill(0) is necessary as .map() will not iterate over undefined array elements.
Update:
By applying the DRY principle ("don't repeat yourself") I can do the same thing in an even shorter way. As the nested map calls are done over the same (unchanged) array of sequential numbers, I might as well define that array as a constant (n20) and apply the nested .map() calls on it.


// create an array of sequential numbers:
const 
  n20=Array(20).fill(0).map((_,i)=>i+1),
  res=n20.map(i=>n20.map(j=>i*j));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;}



This second approach is not only shorter but also computationally more efficient than my previous one.
